# Filter attributes with OR and AND from multiple joined tables in SQLALCHEMY produces extra entity

Tags: python, join, filter, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by), sqlalchemy "filter" and "filter_by" filters only "the last entity that was the target of a call to Query.join()"

I want to have a query like:

```
SELECT sale.*
FROM sale JOIN sale_transactions ON sale.id = sale_transactions.sale_id 
JOIN customer ON customer.id = sale.customer_id 
JOIN product ON product.id = sale_transactions.product_id
WHERE (sale.description LIKE '%something%' OR product.name LIKE '%something%' OR customer.name LIKE '%something%')
AND sale.date >= 'someDate' AND sale.date <= 'someOtherDate'
```

From the modals that I have:

```
class Product(db.Model, ImageFunctions):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    sale_transaction = db.relationship('SaleTransactions', backref='product', lazy='dynamic')

class Customer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), index=True)    
    sale = db.relationship('Sale', backref='customer', lazy='dynamic')

class Sale(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customer.id'))

    transactions = db.relationship('SaleTransactions', backref='sale', lazy='dynamic')

class SaleTransactions(db.Model):    
    sale_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sale.id'), primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True)
    product_qty = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

For this I have written this code:

```
query = Sale.query.join(Customer)
query = query.join(SaleTransactions, Product)
query = query.filter(Sale.description.like('%something%') | Product.name.like('%something%') | Customer.name.like('%something%'))
query = query.filter(Sale.date >= datetime.today(), Sale.date <= datetime.today())
```

But it produces a query with an extra Customer entity without any join but its not the case for the Product because that was last in 'join' statement:

```
SELECT sale.*
FROM customer, sale JOIN sale_transactions ON sale.id = sale_transactions.sale_id 
JOIN customer ON customer.id = sale.customer_id 
JOIN product ON product.id = sale_transactions.product_id
WHERE (sale.description LIKE '%something%' OR product.name LIKE '%something%' OR customer.name LIKE '%something%')
AND sale.date >= 'someDate' AND sale.date <= 'someOtherDate'
```

Is there any way to fix this and not have any extra entity?